# ASP.NET Web API Help Page documentation using Xml comments on controllers

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I installed the [ASP.NET Web API Help Page](http://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.HelpPage/) package and would like to use it to generate documentation for my API controller actions using the Xml comments already on them.

I came across an [article on Yao's MSDN blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/yaohuang1/archive/2012/09/30/asp-net-web-api-help-page-part-1-basic-help-page-customizations.aspx) where he discusses how the documentation can be generated based on the XML comments.

However, in the Register method of `HelpPageConfig`, the `SetDocumentationProvider` method expects an instance of `XmlDocumentationProvider` constructed with a physical path to an Xml documentation file.

Is there another way to do this? I'm not clear why I need to point to an Xml documentation file.

Thanks

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The XmlDocumentationProvider is looking for the xml file(having your xml code comments) which gets generated when you compile your project.
You can enable generating this by going to your project Properties -> Build -> Output. Here select the checkbox for XML Documentation file.

Comment: Kiran, thank you, this does the trick. Is there a good way to programmatically access this value at runtime? Right now I'm doing HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath ...

Comment: thanks a lot for this reply, finally figured out how to get this working.

Comment: Still same, I still see "No documentation available"

Answer (score 45):

If you still problem then see below steps.

**Step 1 - Add comment on the controller level**

```
// GET api/documentation
/// <summary>
/// This is how we create a documentation
/// </summary>
/// <returns></returns>
public IEnumerable<string> Get()
```

**Step 2 - Build Property**
Project Properties page and set up the xml output for documentation

[image]

**Step 3 - HelpPage Config**

To set up the HelpPageConfig to use our documentation xml file, go to `~\Areas\HelpPage\HelpPageConfig.cs`.

By default, the config.SetDocumentationProvider statement is commented out. Use that statement, and point the location of DocumentationProvider to our xml file:

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
   // Uncomment the following to use the documentation from XML documentation file.
   config.SetDocumentationProvider(
            new XmlDocumentationProvider(
                HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/Documentation.xml")));
}
```

**EDIT:**

The location of the HelpPageConfig in a new Web API 2.2 project created in VS2013 is `~\Areas\HelpPage\App_Start\HelpPageConfig.cs`

Comment: The location of the HelpPageConfig in a new Web API 2.2 project created in VS2013 is ~\Areas\HelpPage\App_Start\HelpPageConfig.cs

Comment: @Carl Thank you for the clarification

Answer (score 2):

I know that this question is answered, but in case it helps someone
I have found this page because of looking for solution for documentation for IHttpActionResult

[How to add IHttpActionResult into documentation](http://web.archive.org/web/20190414032629/http://www.cpodesign.com/blog/webapi-helppage-does-not-display-ihttpactionresult-method/)