# Enabling documentation within WebApi2 help page

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a simple webapi2 project.

The only information I can seem to find myself refers to the older webapi1

From my controller if I have

```
   /// <summary>
    /// Gets a list of not very interesting information
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>The list</returns>
   [ResponseType(typeof(ExampleModel))]
    public IHttpActionResult Get()
    {
        var data = new List<ExampleModel>()
        {
            new ExampleModel()
            {
                Date = DateTime.Now,
                Name = "Tom"
            },
            new ExampleModel()
            {
                Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-20),
                Name = "Bob"
            }
        };
```

why is no information appearing when I try browse to the help page. I am told No documentation available.

Is there a magic switch somewhere that will turn on automated population of this data?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ASP.NET Web API Help Page documentation using Xml comments on controllers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14843243/asp-net-web-api-help-page-documentation-using-xml-comments-on-controllers)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

if you referring to displaying the xml comments, then you can find my answer here:

[ASP.NET Web API Help Page documentation using Xml comments on controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14843243/asp-net-web-api-help-page-documentation-using-xml-comments-on-controllers/14843682#14843682)

Be sure to uncomment this code in Areas/HelpPage/App_Start/HelpPageConfig.cs

```
// Uncomment the following to use the documentation from XML documentation file.
config.SetDocumentationProvider(new XmlDocumentationProvider(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/XmlDocument.xml")));
```

Also make sure the xml file goes in App_Data not bin where it defaults to in project properties

Comment: I had tried that without any luck, however based on the date of the post not sure if its still relevant for webapi2

Comment: actually its still relevant to Web API 2 also. BTW, did you uncomment the line of code in `HelpPageConfig.cs` to enable documentation from the xml file?

Comment: I don't get why the xml file has to move to app_data and not bin? I have my xml files in bin and I'm not able to view documentation comments in the server. However local dev works fine.