# Web Api 2 : "Sample not available"

Tags: asp.net, web, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I'm trying to auto generate the help docs for my Web Api.

However I see on one particular method a sample request could not be generated, as shown in the picture:

[image: Image1]

Below are the arguments request parameters:

[image: Image2]

**Why is it unable to generate a sample request format?**

Comment: What you have tried so far? or have you followed any tutorial to achieve this, if yes, then post link?

Comment: @ArindamNayak
I have not followed any tutorials as I've used Web Api 2 For months where it successfully has generated the sample data which is why I wonder why it won't for this particular example.

Comment: This might be helpful -http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14843243/asp-net-web-api-help-page-documentation-using-xml-comments-on-controllers/14843682#14843682

Comment: @ArindamNayak
I tried generating the XML file but I'm still left with the same result, strange as it is.

Answer (score 15):

I have found that actions returning an [`IHttpActionResult`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.ihttpactionresult%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) had a missing sample. In order to get samples generated for these methods I had to decorate the action with a [`ResponseTypeAttribute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.description.responsetypeattribute%28v=vs.118%29.aspx), for example:

```
[ResponseType(typeof(Model))]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Get(int key)
{
    var entity = await dbContext.Models.FindAsync(key);

    if (entity == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    return Ok(entity);
}
```

Comment: Thats the easiest fix for sure.

Comment: Also important to remember that your result class should be public.

Answer (score 9):

Make sure any objects you create have an empty constructor. Objects without an empty constructor cannot be 'automatically' created by the Web API Help Page. If creating an empty constructor is not an option, you could 'manually' create them using the config.SetSampleObjects

Answer (score 5):

For anyone that is curious about which one of these answers between @chris and @wade-wright is correct.

The answer is BOTH.  Both are required.  So for example if you're doing a VM to consolidate content returned by your API to the necessary data you'd be looking at doing something like:

```
[ResponseType(typeof(YourVM))]
```

over top of your controller action

and an empty constructor in your VM:

```
 public class YourVM
    {
        public YourVM() { }
    }
```